# Unity: Updating UI Text's text field draws the new string on top of the previous one

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am working with Unity's `UI.Text`, where I want to show a counter that goes up by 1 every frame. So in `Update()`, I simply do

```
count++;
countText.text = count.ToString();
```

However, instead of the text field getting replaced by the number, the number is drawn on top of the previous number.

[image: example img]

I have used `UI.Text` multiple times before, and never had this issue. What could possibly be happening? Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure that it is on top? Or just updating really fast (depending on your frame rate  might be 60 fps or even 200 depending on your quality settings etc) since you put a new text there `every frame`!

Comment: Enable your camera and if you have your camera `Clear Flags` set to `Don't Clear` change it to `Solid Color`.

Comment: @derHugo Yes, previously I had it increment only when I clicked on a button, and confirmed that "2" was drawn on top of the "1".

Comment: @Pluto I do not use any cameras in this scene, only 2D UI. Is the advice still applicable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a `Camera` to your scene. (It says "Display 1 - No cameras rendering" in your screenshot).

`Menu -> GameObject -> Camera`

Without a Camera and just a Text, what you described will happen - Text will not be cleared between `Update` calls.

Edit: as per Pluto's comment, also check that Camera's `Clear Flags` setting is set to `Solid Color` or `Skybox`, and not `Don't Clear`.